# Object is not setup correctly when passing it across classes

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble pushing new ViewController in swift.

```
class CartViewController: UITableViewController  {

    static var items:[Item] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return CartViewController.items.count
    }

    //if cell is selected
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PaymentController") as! PaymentController
        print(CartViewController.items[indexPath.row].title)
        vc.item? = CartViewController.items[indexPath.row]

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

The print function up there gives the right result, but there's nothing showing up when the new vc is pushed. debugger shows the 
`vc.item`
 is nil.

This is what I have in PaymentController class

```
class PaymentController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet weak var myTitle: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var myPrice: UILabel?

    var item:Item?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myImage?.image = UIImage(named: item!.image)
        myTitle?.text = item!.title
        myPrice?.text = String(item!.price)
    }
}
```

Any hints or ideas will be appreciated:))

Comment: In `tableView(_,didSelectRowAt:)` try removing the `?` in line 3. I.e., replace `vc.item? = (...)` with `vc.item = (...)` .

Comment: thanks for replying Yonat, it workes like a charm!

Comment: Cool, posted as answer below.

Comment: Is there a special need to use ```static``` for this variable: ```var items:[Item] = []``` ?
Why not removing ```static```, and use ```self.items``` everywhere, instead of ```CartViewController.items``` ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Starsky, the reason I'm using ```static``` is because I want to make sure there is only 1 ```items``` exist and access to the list from other classes as well. However, I'm kind new to swift and not sure if there's any easier ways to do it, if you have any ideas, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tableView(_,didSelectRowAt:)` try removing the `?` in line 3.
I.e., replace `vc.item? = (...)` with `vc.item = (...)`